# Send temp file with jax-rs

Tags: java, file, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to send a temporary file with jax-rs and delete the temporary file once the download is done. For that purpose I subclassed InputSream in order to be notified once the stream is closed. This is what I have so far:

```
@GET
@Path("download/{fileName}")
public Response downloadFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) {
    InputStream inputStream = new InputStreamWithFileDeletion(new getFile(filename));

    Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename="+"fileName"+".xls");
    return response.build();
}
```

InputStreamWithFileDeletion:

```
public class InputStreamWithFileDeletion extends FileInputStream {
    File f;

    public InputStreamWithFileDeletion(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
        f = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        f.delete();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, once the download is done, close() is not called. Am I missing something?

Comment: JAX-RS has default support for java.io.File object - but I wonder if its applicable to your scenario since you are creating a temporary file rather than returning contents of a static file. If it were a static file on disk: `@Path("/file")
public class FileDownloadService {
@GET
@Path("location")
@Produces("text/plain")
public File getFile(@PathParam("location") String path) {
return new File(path);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
```

to

```
Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Sven Junga's answer, I came up with this solution:

```
Path p = Paths.get(tempFile);
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(p);
Files.delete(p);
return Response.ok(is).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=f.txt").build();
```

The file will be deleted as soon as the input stream is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
InputStream inputStream = new InputSreamWithFileDelition(new getFile(filename));
```

to

```
InputSreamWithFileDelitioninputStream = new InputSreamWithFileDelition(new getFile(filename));
```

to make sure to call the good `close` method.

Then implement `AutoCloseAble` in your `InputStreamWithFileDelition` class which will call by default your overriden close method.

Comment: @Savard Thanks, but system still does not want to call `close()` method.

Comment: @Savard It was my original idea, but there is no straight forward way to determine that the download is finished. My guess was that the `close()` function is called right a way, but it is not called once download is finished.

Comment: It looks like `cluse()` is actually called, but only through GC

Comment: @Chort409 Are you sure that your `delete` method works as you expect it, have you tried calling it another way to see if the result is correct ? I find it strange that the above suggestion does not call the proper method. If you put a print statement in your `close` implementation, does it get displayed ?